# How to keep user logged in (Aka, state persistency) in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to keep a user logged in in my application. I tried several techniques but i have no idea on how i can read data back into the state when the application launches.

Right now i have the following:

```
const getInitialState = () => {
    var _initState = {
        auth: new AuthInitialState(),
        global: (new GlobalInitialState())
    };

    return _initState;
};

export default function configureStore() {


    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, load(APP_STORAGE) || getInitialState());

    store.subscribe(() => {
        if(!load('debug')) {
            save(APP_STORAGE, store.getState());
        }
    });

    return store;
};

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    thunk,
    localStorageMiddleware,
    logger
)(createStore)
```

In which the load and save methods are responsible for saving data to an AsyncStorage (using react-native-simple-store)

```
export const load = (key) => {
    return store.get(key);
}

export const save = async (key, data) => {
    store.save(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

The render of my root is the current:

```
render() {
    const store = configureStore();

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MyApp/>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

The data is being correctly saved (through the save subscriber) but it is not correctly reloaded on a hot reload or app relaunch. Thus my user ends up being logged out every time.

In the end i would also like to apply this technique to navigate to the correct page upon app startup.

Any recommendations on how i can approach this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to achieve this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default function configureStore() {

   const store = createStore(reducers, getInitialState(), compose(
       applyMiddleware([
           thunk,
           localStorageMiddleware,
           logger
       ]),
       autoRehydrate()
      )
   );

   persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage });

   return store;
};
```

With this, each time your application load, the store is hydrated from the local storage. You don't have to deal with the `AsyncStorage`, everything is done automatically for you. You can [read the docs](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md) of `redux-persist` to customize it per your needs (add a `whitelist`, a `blacklist`, a callback when the store is rehydrated..)

Comment: For now i am using this one, works perfectly thanks !

Comment: Note that `autoRehydrate` is now deprecated and to use `PersistGate` in your top-level component, as per the `redux-persist` docs

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach looks good to me.

However, react-native-simple-store stringifies the state for you. As you run `JSON.stringify()` in your save function as well, it will not properly get decoded when it is loaded during the next start of your app.

See [react-native-simple-store's codebase](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/blob/2bf2d3797370c2ce92e9958165969d2db9ef4fa5/src/index.js#L37) for more details.

---

To resolve this, **remove `JSON.stringify()` from your save function**:

```
export const save = async (key, data) => {
    store.save(key, data);
}
```

Comment: But then i am having problems with the Promise being returned upon loading the data

`export const load = async (key) => {
    return await store.get(key);
}`